# Soul Vessels in Pillars of Eternity

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I let Nridek in Lhe a Rhemen ruins live and saved afterwards before I knew i needed the soul vessel.  Is there a way to get another soul vessel?

Comment: Well is there some benefit to allowing him to live?

Comment: I didn't run across any further reference in the game or the ending slides, so just your conscience it would seem.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

There is no way to acquire another Soul Vessel. The benefit of allowing him to live is that you did not sacrifice countless lives for your own personal gain.